# invalid literal for int() with base 10 Keras pad sequence

Tags: keras, sequence, preprocessor

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/ProjetFinal/venv/turkish.py", line 45, in <module>
    sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_len)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\ProjetFinal\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\sequence.py", line 96, in pad_sequences
    trunc = np.asarray(trunc, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\ProjetFinal\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

windows loading  yapıo sonra mavi ekran iste. simdi repair yapıyo bkalım olmazsa
 gelirim size.

[image]

Comment: Please explain your problem in bit more detail.                                                                As of now looking at the error, somewhere code is trying to type cast 'ustadim onu ben de cozemedim ama 10 gune geliyom hallderiz bi sekil.' which is not INTEGER. check if you have converted text into numerical before using pad sequence.

Comment: X = dft.text
Y = dft.type
le = LabelEncoder()
Y = le.fit_transform(Y)
Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.15)

# %% [code]
max_words = 1000
max_len = 150
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
sequences = str(X_train)
sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_len) **this is what my code look like i casted the X_Train having the TypeError: len() of unsized object issue **  still searching for an answer ..

Comment: The error says something is expecting integers and you're passing `'ustadim onu ben de cozemedim ama 10 gune geliyom hallderiz bi sekil.'` to it.

Answer (score -1):

```
X = dft.text
```

your straight using text with pad_sequence. this is how pad_sequence doesn't work

Generally, every text is converted into numbers within a given vocab which can be of characters or words depend upon task.
then it can be padded.

please refer some tutorial through you can understand how to process text first.

Tensorflow tutorials - text part are good to start.
   https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding